# Strtok:I dont know why this program keeps failing

Tags: c

In this program the char *token is initialized with a weird garbage value.I am unable to sort it out. Here's the source code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void fetch_value(char *string,int pos,char *dest)
{
    char *token;
    int i=0;
    token=strtok(string,",");
    if(pos>1)
    {
        token=strtok(NULL,",");
        while(i<pos-1){
            token=strtok(NULL,",");
            printf("token =%s\n",token);
            i++;
        }
        strcpy(dest,token);
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(dest,token);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char checking[100];
    memset(checking,0x00,sizeof(checking));
    fetch_value("14174000100,35679700322,35679700322,35679700322,
            35679700322,14174000999,919440710210000,1",0,checking);
    printf("checking=%s\n",checking);
    return 0;
}
```

Your help, feedback or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this as "c". What is `<iostream>`  doing here? That's C++ and unneeded.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of `strtok` must be modifiable. Your code passes a string literal, which is *not* modifiable. This leads to undefined behavior.

The simplest modification that will fix the problem is as follows:

```
char numList[] = "14174000100,35679700322,35679700322,35679700322,35679700322,14174000999,919440710210000,1";
fetch_value(numList, 0, checking);
```

You should also note that `strtok` is an older function which is not reentrant, because it uses static variables to save its state. In the new code you should use the reentrant version of the function - [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), which requires you to pass memory for saving the state.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
 int main(void)
   {
     char checking[100];
     memset(checking,0x00,sizeof(checking));
     char string[] = "14174000100,35679700322,35679700322,35679700322,
     35679700322,14174000999,919440710210000,1";
     //now string can be modified.
     fetch_value(&string[0],0,checking);
     printf("checking=%s\n",checking);
     return 0;
    }
```